# Implement 2D convolution using FFT

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, fft

`TensorFlow.conv2d()` is impractically slow for convolving large images with large kernels (filters). It takes a few minutes to convolve a 1024x1024 image with a kernel of the same size. For comparison, `cv2.filter2D()` returns the result immediately.

I found `tf.fft2()` and `tf.rfft()`.

However it was not clear to me how to perform simple image filtering with these functions.

How can I implement fast 2D image filtering with TensorFlow using FFT?

Comment: I don't know about Tensorflow, but I think you can use [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) to do this.

Comment: `tf.nn.conv2d` is pretty well optimized; are you including graph construction time in the "a few minutes"? In which case you could try `tf.enable_eager_execution()`. Hard to say more without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) way to reproduce the performance issue you're asking about.

Comment: fft2 is not working in tensorflow.

Answer (score 6):

A linear discrete convolution of the form `x * y` can be computed using convolution theorem and the discrete time Fourier transform (DTFT). If `x * y` is a circular discrete convolution than it can be computed with the discrete Fourier transform (DFT).

The convolution theorem states `x * y` can be computed using the Fourier transform as

[image: Convolution theorem]

where [image: Fourier transform] denotes the Fourier transform and [image: Inverse Fourier transform] the inverse Fourier transform. When `x` and `y` are discrete and their convolution is a linear convolution this is computed using the DTFT as

[image: Discrete convolution theorem]

If `x` and `y` are discrete and their convolution is a circular convolution the DTFT above is replaced by the DFT. **Note:** linear convolution problems can be embedded in circular convolution problems.

---

I'm more familiar with MATLAB but from reading the TensorFlow documentation for [`tf.signal.fft2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft2d) and [`tf.signal.ifft2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/ifft2d) the solution below should be easily convertible to TensorFlow by replacing the MATLAB functions `fft2` and `ifft2`.

In MATLAB (and TensorFlow) `fft2` (and `tf.signal.fft2d`) computes the DFT using the fast Fourier transform algorithm. If the convolution of `x` and `y` is circular this can be computed by

```
ifft2(fft2(x).*fft2(y))
```

where `.*` represents element by element multiplication in MATLAB. However, if it is linear then we zero pad the data to length `2N-1` where `N` is the length of one dimension (1024 in the question). In MATLAB this can be computed one of two ways. Firstly, by

```
h = ifft2(fft2(x, 2*N-1, 2*N-1).*fft2(y, 2*N-1, 2*N-1));
```

where MATLAB computes the `2*N-1`-point 2D Fourier transform of `x` and `y` by zero padding and then the `2*N-1`-point 2D inverse Fourier transform. This method can't be used in TensorFlow (from my understanding of the documentation) so the next is the only option. In MATLAB and TensorFlow the convolution can be computed by first extending `x` and `y` to size `2*N-1` x `2*N-1` and then computing the `2*N-1`-point 2D Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform

```
x_extended = x;
x_extended(2*N-1, 2*N-1) = 0;

y_extended = y;
y_extended(2*N-1, 2*N-1) = 0;

h_extended = ifft2(fft2(x_extended).*fft2(y_extended));
```

In MATLAB, `h` and `h_extended` are exactly equal. The convolution of `x` and `y` can be computed without the Fourier transform with

```
hC = conv2(x, y);
```

in MATLAB.

---

In MATLAB on my laptop `conv2(x, y)` takes 55 seconds whereas the Fourier transform approach takes less than 0.4 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a way similar to which for instance `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` is implemented.

Here is an example, assume we have an image (2 dimensions, if you have also multiple channels you can use the 3d instead of 2 functions) (im), and a filter (e.g. gaussian).

First, take the Fourier transform of the image and define the `fft_lenghts` (useful if the filter is of a different shape, in which case it will get zero padded.)

```
fft_lenght1 = tf.shape(im)[0]
fft_lenght2 = tf.shape(im)[1]
im_fft = tf.signal.rfft2d(im, fft_length=[fft_lenght1, fft_lenght2])
```

Next, take the FFT of the filter (note, for instance for a 2d gaussian filter make sure the center is in the top left corner, i.e. use only a 'quarter')

```
kernel_fft = tf.signal.rfft2d(kernel, fft_length=[fft_lenght1, fft_lenght2])
```

Finally, take the inverse transform back to get the convolved image

```
im_blurred = tf.signal.irfft2d(im_fft * kernel_fft, [fft_lenght1, fft_lenght2])
```